# Relation Subtraction wrong result

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries:

Query1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='laptop'
```

Gives result `{A, B, E, F, G}`

and

Query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='pc'
```

Gives result `{A, B, C, D, E}`

**The question is**:
How can I get `query1 - query2 = {A, B, E, F, G} - {A, B, C, D, E} = {F, G}`

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='pc' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='b'
);
```

But it gave me empty record. Sorry I'm new with MySQL

Comment: The inner query always returns something, so the `NOT EXISTS` is always false - you need to limit it to the `maker` you are just checking. Or you can use `maker NOT IN(..)` instead of `NOT EXISTS` to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `NOT IN` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker 
FROM Product 
WHERE type='pc' 
  AND maker  NOT IN
 (
    SELECT maker 
    FROM Product
    WHERE type='b'
      AND maker IS NOT NULL -- to prevent empty results
 );
```

Caution: This will not work correctly with a `NULL` maker.

The recommended solution is `NOT EXISTS`, but you need a *Correlated* Subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker 
FROM Product AS p1
WHERE type='pc'
  AND NOT EXISTS
 (
    SELECT maker
    FROM Product AS p2
    WHERE type='b'
      AND p1.maker = p2.maker -- correlation to the outer SELECT
 );
```

If MySQL supported `EXCEPT` it would be a simple

```
SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE type='pc'
EXCEPT
SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE type='b';
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use grouping and check the results of certain aggregated values:

```
SELECT
  maker
FROM
  Product
GROUP BY
  maker
HAVING
  COUNT(type = 'laptop' OR NULL) > 0
  AND COUNT(type = 'pc' OR NULL) = 0
;
```

The HAVING conditions specify that each maker group must have at least one `type = 'laptop'` row and no `type = 'pc'` rows.

Basically, the COUNT expression return the number of rows matching the specified type, for each group. (A detailed explanation of the purpose of `OR NULL` in these COUNTs can be found in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011239/why-do-i-need-or-null-in-mysql-when-counting-rows-with-a-condition/5011311#5011311).) You could replace the COUNTs with equivalent SUMs:

```
HAVING
  SUM(type = 'laptop') > 0
  AND SUM(type = 'pc') = 0
```

and thus make the expressions much shorter without changing the results. It is just a matter of preference for me to use COUNT when it is about counting.

Note: The query uses the type values from your description rather than from your attempted query.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions

## SUGGESTION #1

You should put each query in a subquery then do a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT A.maker
FROM      (SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='laptop') A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='pc')     B
USING (maker) WHERE B.maker IS NULL;
```

## SUGGESTION #2

Add this compound index to speed up the subqueries

```
ALTER TABLE Product ADD INDEX type_maker_ndx (type,maker);
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## CAVEAT

Please note you said you tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='pc' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='b'
);
```

You probably meant

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='pc' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='laptop'
);
```